# infer type from optional constructor function parameter's return type

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```
type DefaultType = {.....};
class A<MyInferedType> {
  constructor(
    private readonly paramFunc: (response: MyInferedType) => any,
    private readonly optionalParamFunc?: () => Promise<MyInferedType>
  ) {}
  async doSomething() {
    // note the else branch! if optionalParamFunc is not defined i want to use a DefaultType value
    const result = this.optionalParamFunc ? this.optionalParamFunc() : {} as DefaultType ;
    this.paramFunc(result);
  }
}
```

I want `MyInferedType` to be infered from the `optionalParamFunc` if that is passed to the constructor. If it's not passed, i want it to be `DefaultType`.
I was playing around with the infer keyword, but i had no success. I guess some experts can explain me what is the right approach for this.

I should be able to use it as follows:

```
const defVal: DefaultType = {...};
const inferedVal: AnyTypeOfChoice = {...};
const a = new A((defVal) => {...});
const a2 = new A((inferedVal) => {...}, async () => inferedVal);
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AFXNAvFA3lACYBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOZQC%20A3AFCiRQByA9gEk68CFQA8GAHxQ8AbQwBdeVAgAPYBDpFyURHRBQA-FAAMUMnQgA3UQo4BjVInI6AgmICyIISKoQiWNx4cEhomNjS%20OxQUPZ8dJRUyPbAfFQAFNExUGC0VogaUH6IRPGoBmCIVIgAtgBiyHT2ZOl%205GDx5BBkXj6i-oEQAJQy0nogADRZMbk0%20YXFpXTlUHxgwDTxiKgAClW1DU2GLSM40jtUfDU0XZ7ewv0BEVkj%20MzsWc4gTcR8AMpXCDAAAW9AY6Ve0ygAHpoVA6HxCiDoBBUF0oAAjapNYEAQigNHgq3Wmzo2z21XqjXsBJ0COAxAQ9H8BKgAHc9AzUlBkOjELAECh0IMoPlUMgIFC4gkGW0wjIoCCbgA6NYbLa7fZUn7GRAcmhc0HkVUkjUUg7UiHmAikKAAImc2hKdrYUKVxsqlMO9laEHIYSGHBi73enGwUFc%20kGAHl4ABhYF8Gj2aAKqIxRAWZA1DGidjvaWURnwABq2zIISF4SCBGIZDtLocnQZ9F8-jLqDIkZAMfjieTuFrmagAFZXYWGfy8JY2RH0ukiAgO6dIsWO8qiCxA%20wJ7oAEwKmdz9Ktx7L0a109%20Ijr-nMCa6cjfGlWs4Eh7X5esIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the inference behavior of conditional types (ie the `infer` keyword). A simple parameter type default seems to do the job:

```
type DefaultType = { d: string };
class A<MyInferedType = DefaultType> {
  constructor(
    private readonly paramFunc: (response: MyInferedType) => any,
    private readonly optionalParamFunc?: () => Promise<MyInferedType>
  ) {}
}

type AnyTypeOfChoice  = {a: string }
const defVal: DefaultType = { d: ""};
const inferedVal: AnyTypeOfChoice = { a: ""};
const a = new A((defVal) => { defVal.d });
const a2 = new A((inferedVal) => { inferedVal.a }, async () => inferedVal);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2AFXNAvFA3lACYBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOZQC+A3AFCiRQByA9gEk68CFQA8GAHxQ8AbQwBdeVAgAPYBDpFyURHRBQA-FAAMUMnQgA3UQo4BjVInI6AgmICyIISKoQiWNx4cEhomNjS+OxQUPZ8dJRUyPbAfFQAFNExUGC0VogaUH6IRPGoBmCIVIgAtgBiyHT2ZOl+5GDx5BBkXj6i-oEQAJQy0nogADRZMbk0+YXFpXTlUHxgwDTxiKgAClW1DU2GLSM40jtUfDU0XZ7ewv0BEVkj+Mzs75zYUK76gwDy8AAwgALPg0ezQGQELKIMiJegMD7sOIJYDEBAANW2ZBCKHQg2hhFIUAARKS2CjOuj6L5-NjUGRfiAAcCwRDcARdGRyZTUZRdNDLAB3H7pdJELHbU6RDHwBkAOiILCGDmpugATEKIKLXOLaY8GTKuQa-ERFYgWBNdOQQE0oOljab6dLWEA)

With regard to the problem of instantiating a value of a generic type parameter, that is something that TS in principle does not allow. From a typing perspective there is no relation between the check `this.optionalParamFunc` and the type parameter `MyInferedType`, so as far as ts is concerned any you can't instantiate `MyInferedType` because you really have no idea what it fully looks like.

You can get around this using a type assertion:

```
const result = this.optionalParamFunc ? await this.optionalParamFunc() : {d: "asdsad"} as any as MyInferedType;
```

Be advised we can conceive an instantiation that actually has  `this.optionalParamFunc` undefined, while not having the type parameter `DefaultType`. (`new A<AnyTypeOfChoice>((inferedVal) => { inferedVal.a })`)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately this way i can't use the paramFunc with a DefaulType parameter. Check my edited question for details.

Comment: Also check my playground link for the specific error message i get.

Comment: @Jumi that is a different issue.  You can't really know inside the class what the type parameter is. While your check is logically sufficient, it will not satisfy the  TS compiler. A type assertion is your best choice inside the class `const result = this.optionalParamFunc ? await this.optionalParamFunc() : {d: "asdsad"} as any as MyInferedType;`

Comment: I can't really belive it :D Until i find some solution that fits my expectations, can you update your answer with this information? So i can mark it as the most helpful for finding a "solution".

Comment: @Jumi added to the answer.